# Are Circular Reference(-tables related that form a circle) flaw in databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, circular-reference

In my DB i have to do a `Circular Reference(cycle)` to get the data i want, and i don't know how to do reorder the tables to get the data i want without cycle.

Here's the schema(-or model) of my DB --only the table names are in english(my native language is spanish), the columns are in spanish:
[image: db]

This DB is designed for a bus station, to manage the tickets sales, this model is bad because the table 'TICKET' should be related to 'TRIP_BUS' because that's the table that store what bus will do a trip at any time in the schedule, but i need to know to what seat that ticket belongs to, so in this model i have to do next:

1. Delete the relation between 'TICKET' and 'SEAT', then create an intermediate table(--let's call it 'TICKET_SEAT') between the to relate from Many-to-Many so that the same seat can be recorded for many tickets of the different trips that the bus do.
2. Relate 'TRIP_BUS' to 'TICKET' from One-to-Many (--'TRIP_BUS' PK will be FK in 'TICKET') to know from what trip and bus the ticket is.

If i do this i'll get a Cycle between

TRIP_BUS **->** BUS **<-** SECTION **<-** SEAT **->** TICKET_SEAT **<-** TICKET **<-** TRIP_BUS

All those tables form a circle, i'm not sure if at any point the consistency of the data will be lost.

- The main question is: Are circular reference a flaw in DB?
- In this case the circular reference is the only way to get the
  necesary data?

Comment: Transitive foreign key references are a form of denormalization, and thus are in consequence an anti-pattern to be avoided.

Comment: i haven't heard about them, can u explain?

Comment: I think you're going about this wrong.  For any given bus trip, there can only be one ticket sold per seat.  How can that be a Many-to-Many relationship?  If ti is, you might not have it set up properly.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really a cycle as you can't follow relationships from the many end to the one end and get back where you started.

What you have is two different paths leading from seat to trip_bus. This is perfectly fine. However, it is a smell that you might have additional constraints lurking.

Take a simplified example with just `Bus`, `Seat`, `Trip` and `Ticket`.

`Bus` has a primary key of `BusId`

`Seat` has a primary key of `SeatId` and a foreign key of `BusId`

`Trip` has a primary key of `TripId` and a foreign key of `BusId`

If we additionally define unique indexes on `Seat` of `(BusId, SeatId)` and on `Trip` of `(BusId, TripId)` then we can make `Ticket` be
`(TicketId, BusId, SeatId, TripId)` with foreign keys on `(BusId, SeatId)` and `(BusId, TripId)`.

This structure means you can't have a ticket for a trip on one bus, but a seat on a different bus.

If we additionally make `(BusId, SeatId, TripId)` unique on ticket then it creates the constraint that each seat can only have one ticket per trip.

Comment: Did u read the schema of the db?, the answer you're giving me is similar of what i've described in the post.

Comment: I don't see BusId on the ticket table, which was the point I was trying to make. With your schema, it looks like you could enter a ticket with a trip on one bus, but a seat on a different one.

Comment: The image of the schema is wrong(i put it in the description) the solution i propose is after the third paragraph, where i say: "so in this model i have to do next:" analize it, it gives me the solution you tell, but in you solution there's a problem, i trip can only be done by one bus. that's why i create the table 'TRIP_BUS', beforehand thanks for help me:D